# How to extract a submatrix without making a copy in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large matrix, and I need to extract a small matrix taken from a sliding window which runs all over the large matrix, but during the operations the content of the extracted matrix does not change, so I'd like to extract the submatrix without creating a new copy but instead just acts like a C pointer that points to a portion of the large matrix. How can I do this? Please help me, thank you very much :)

Comment: There aren't any pointers in MATLAB, you could keep track of the bounds on your submatrix and reference the original matrix like this `M(rmin:rmax, cmin:cmax)`

Comment: @jodag But if I write A = M(rmin:rmax, cmin:cmax) wouldn't it create a new matrix ? And writing M(rmin:rmax, cmin:cmax) is a little bit verbose :(

Comment: Yes that would create a new matrix. And likely a new matrix would be allocated anyway when a computation is done on the submatrix no matter what. MATLAB isn't a low level language like C and you don't directly have control over your memory allocation. There are no pointers in MATLAB.

Comment: @jodag what about function handle ? :(

Comment: What specific problems are being caused by the allocation of the submatrix? If you are concerned about efficiency (and speed), why are you writing your own sliding window code rather than using builtins?

Comment: @jodag So Matlab indeed does not have something like a pointer, but it does have references (implicit, like in e.g. C#). You can easily demonstrate that by passing large matrices to functions, but do or do not return them , with and without modifying in the function body.

Comment: @beaker Actually that was because i did not about any builtins available for the task :(

Comment: @DangManhTruong This is the very definition of premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I did some benchmarking to test if not using an explicit temporary matrix is faster, and it's probably not:

```
function move_mean(N)
M = randi(100,N);
window_size = [50 50];
dir_time = timeit(@() direct(M,window_size))
tmp_time = timeit(@() with_tmp(M,window_size))
end

function direct(M,window_size)
m = zeros(size(M)./2);
for r = 1:size(M,1)-window_size(1)
    for c = 1:size(M,2)-window_size(2)
        m(r,c) = mean(mean(M(r:r+window_size(1),c:c+window_size(2))));
    end
end
end

function with_tmp(M,window_size)
m = zeros(size(M)./2);
for r = 1:size(M,1)-window_size(1)
    for c = 1:size(M,2)-window_size(2)
        tmp = M(r:r+window_size(1),c:c+window_size(2));
        m(r,c) = mean(mean(tmp));
    end
end
end
```

for `M` at size 100*100:

```
dir_time =
      0.22739
tmp_time =
      0.22339
```

So it's seems like using a temporary variable only makes your code readable, not slower.

Comment: Actually I think that the difference in your test lies in the double call to `mean` in the direct case, if you change the temp case code to `mean(mean(tmp))`, then there is no difference

Comment: @NoelSegura you right, I was too sloppy. Edited my answer to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I describe what is the 'best' solution in general. For this answer I define 'best' as most readable without a significant performance hit. (Partially shown by the existing answer).

Basically there are 2 situations that you may be in.

## 1. You use your submatrix several times

In this situation the best solution in general is to create a temporary variable containing the submatrix.

```
A = M(rmin:rmax, cmin:cmax)
```

There may be ways around it (defining a function/anonymous function that indexes into the matrix for you), but in general that won't make you happy.

## 2. You use your submatrix only 1 time

In this case the best solution is typically exactly what you referred to in the comments:

```
M(rmin:rmax, cmin:cmax)
```

A specific case of using the submatrix only 1 time, is when it is passed once to  a function. Of course the contents of the submatrix may be used in that function several times, but that is irrelevant.